# Ordering a list based on keys from another list

Tags: python, list

Let's say we have a list A that has been ordered according to some function and another list B that should serve as keys. How can I return a list that preserves the original ordering of A, but with the values of B in front of the values not in B?

```
# Scenario I.
A = ['a','b','c','d']
B = ['b','d']
# Want to return: ['b','d','a','c']

# Scenario II.
A = ['a','b','c','d']
B = ['d','b']
# Want to return: ['b','d','a','c']

# Scenario III.
A = ['a','b','c','d']
B = ['d','c','b','a']
# Want to return: ['a','b','c','d']
```

Comment: Take a look at the `partition` function from the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). In this case, your predicate would be `lambda x: x in B`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am overthinking it. Something like this would work, but probably not the most efficient/elegant way:

```
C = [x for x in A if x in B] # Preserves order of A since it loops through one-by-one
D = [x for x in A if x not in B]
E = C + D
```

Answer (score 0):

For each item in A, if it's in B, put it in one list, otherwise put it in another list, then return the two lists together.

```
def prefer_b(a, b):
    """
    Return a list of items from "a" with the ones that are also in "b" first.

    >>> prefer_b('abcd', 'bd')
    ['b', 'd', 'a', 'c']
    >>> prefer_b('abcd', 'db')
    ['b', 'd', 'a', 'c']
    >>> prefer_b('abcd', 'dcba')
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    """
    in_b, not_in_b = [], []
    for item in a:
        lst = in_b if item in b else not_in_b
        lst.append(item)
    return in_b + not_in_b
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function and it did the trick for me

```
def func(A,B):
    Z = [x for x in A if x not in B]

    return sorted(B) + Z
```

You start by excluding overlaps in A and end by merging a sorted B with A.
I assume B should be sorted since your second example does that.